# Question on .submit and reloading form values AFTER the submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.4.3 and have a newbie question.

In the following .submit function, I  grab the value of the selected option in the facilityCodes dropdown list after I click the submit button and then during the submit function, select the facilityCode again in the dropdown list and then disable the list so that the user cannot change it.  However, the situation is when I reload the page after the submit button is clicked the dropdown defaults to the first option and the list is enabled.  I apparently am not understanding how .submit works so that I'm selecting the option I'm defining in my code and then disabling the list AFTER the page reloads.  My question is what am I doing wrong?  Am I using the wrong event?

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#ARTransferForm").submit(function() {
            var msgsCount = 0;

            var facilityCodeValue = $("#ARTransferForm\\:facilityCodes option:selected").val();
alert("facilityCodeValue = " + facilityCodeValue);
            if (facilityCodeValue == 0) {
                alert("To Facility Code must be selected");
                msgsCount++;
            } else {
                $('select[id$=facilityCodes]').val(facilityCodeValue);
                $("#ARTransferForm\\:facilityCodes").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
                });
});
```

Comment: If the page is reloaded, there is a good chance that the elements are reset. ESPECIALLY with a POST and also if caching is off

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the page will erase everything you've done with JavaScript prior to the page refresh. If you're looking to preserve states through page reloads, you'll need to use server side code, or set a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

The submit event is called on the current page when the form is about to post. You'll need to pass along a value (hidden field) that is checked on form load that you can check to determine if the list should be disabled.

Update:

On page load, you'll want to check to see if this is a repost where the hidden field id="disable_select" was set set during the post. If so, then you'll disable the form.

```
$(function(){
    if ($('#disable_select').val() == '1') {
        $("#ARTransferForm\\:facilityCodes").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I wanted to make sure that I'm understanding what you're suggesting regarding the hidden field.  I am setting a hidden field in my form. I noticed after the page reloaded that the hidden field was populated with the option I want to select.  Can I do this by using the following:

$(function() {
  $("#ARTransferForm").load(function() {
   var hiddenFacCodeValue = $("#ARTransferForm\\:selectedFacilityCodeValue").val();
   if (hiddenFacCodeValue != "0") {
    $('select[id$=facilityCodes]').val(hiddenFacCodeValue);
   }
  });
 });

Your help is appreciated.  Regards.

Comment: Updating answer with more details. The hidden field should only contain a marker to let you know that the select should be disabled.

Comment: Got my problem resolved and working.  .load() in jQuery did not resolve my issue.  I went back to the onload javascript method and was able to resolve selecting the option based on a hidden value captured after the page was reloaded and do what I needed to with it.

Again, appreciate the replies and help.

Regards.